# Issue with Bootstrap mobile menu not appearing

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 on a site and I found a weird bug that I can't figure out. It deals with the mobile menu on smaller devices. When I view the site on iOS I can see the menu icon appear, but when I click on the icon the menu does not show up. However, if I then click an area where the menu should appear, the link works and takes me to a page.

To add another variable to the problem, when I view it in chrome with the dev tools acting as iOS and the screen small, the menu shows up and works as intended. So I am at a loss how to debug the issue.

I have tried setting the z-index to 1000 with no luck. I have not been able to find documentation regarding this issue. If you have run into this issue or know where there is documentation for it I would really appreciate some help.

Here is a link to the site with the issue(on mobile devices). http://dd.cakeandeatitdesigns.com

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey in my personal experience working with that it could happened when you open your web page with safari in IOS. I don't know what are you using to show the lateral menu, but some times safari doesn't work with certain js.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have tried it in both safari and chrome on iOS and the issue persists.

Comment: You could debug your web app in Firefox to figure out what is happening there. Look this link https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html

Comment: Yeah, I am looking into different options for debugging iOS since it seems this isn't a know bug. Thanks!